# How to access multiple files in SparkR using wildcards

Tags: sparkr

I have multiple files located in nested folders, for example:

/bucket/folder1/foloder2/folder3/data.csv

I want to access all the data.json files located in folder2, I can do the same using scala using following code:

```
sc.textFile("/bucket/folder1/*/folder3/data.json")
```

**How can achieve the same using SparkR?**

Tried using sparkR:::textFile

```
my_rdd<-SparkR:::textFile(sc,"/bucket/folder1/*/folder3/data.json")
```

but getting the following error-

16/09/14 16:02:48 ERROR RBackendHandler: defaultParallelism on 1 failed
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Spark 2.0**:

```
df <- read.json("/bucket/folder1/*/folder3/data.json")
```

Notice that all contents will be loaded into a SparkDataFrame and a SparkR session needs to be created previously: `sparkR.session()`.

In **Spark 1.6.2**:

```
df <- read.json(sqlContext, "/bucket/folder1/*/folder3/data.json")
```

Notice that a sqlContext needs to be created previously: `sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)`.

Comment: Getting following error:
05:04:20 ERROR RBackendHandler: json on 2 failed
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) :

Comment: Is this the complete exception message, no stack trace? Does it work with a minimal json object {"key":"value"}?

Comment: it's solved, there was issue with permissions nothing to do with SparkR